# Tkinter, getting the widget that triggered an Event

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a way to check which event key was pressed. I'm trying to call on a function by knowing which key was pressed. It must be inside one function.

```
from tkinter import *

def check(event):
    if Up was pressed:
        Up()

    elif Down was pressed:
        Down()

    elif Left was pressed:
        Left()

    else:
        Right()

root= Tk()

root.bind("<Up>", check)
root.bind("<Down>", check)
root.bind("<Left>", check)
root.bind("<Right>", check)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.key`. With this you also don't need to use `root.bind()` more than one time:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def Key(event):
    if event.keycode == 37:
        print('Left')
    if event.keycode == 38:
        print('Up')
    if event.keycode == 39:
        print('Right')
    if event.keycode == 40:
        print('Down')

root.bind('<Key>', Key)
root.mainloop()
```

To get the codes you can use this:

```
def getKeycode(event): print(event.keycode)

root.bind('<Key>', getKeycode)
root.mainloop()
```

## Further reading:

- [Tkinter events and bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Comment: Thanks man, this worked ! I'd up vote, but my reputation won't allow it.. I appreciate the help.